# Using urls to route to a scroll location on a webpage

Tags: html, url, url-routing

I'm wondering if it could be considered bad practice to use a url to reference a position on a webpage.

For example, the url http://example.com/page/item would load 'page.html' and tell a javascript function to scroll to the position of 'item'. Much like using #anchors. Basically it's like subpages, but all are placed on the same page.

One immediate problem that comes to mind is that there is no way to deal with anyone not using javascript. (or is there?)

Another is having items change names, or even switch pages. Which breaks any links, but that's not really any different from regular sub-pages and could be redirected by some sort of server side check.

Thoughts on this?

Comment: Front-end JavaScript frameworks basically do something similar. Based on the URL, they choose what to show and what to hide on the website. No one really complains. If you want this working without JS, you could simply use anchors (and intercept them and convert to these "nice" urls using JS, where available).

Comment: Thanks for the info! you could add that as an answer and I'd accept it.